# What is the best way to deal with Django form validation involving FieldFile attachments?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I currently have a Django app and am using the built in form validation to generate form errors upon user submission.  Everything works fine.  My issue is that I am allowing users to attach files to the page...and if the form validation fails, the files disappear and the user has to reattach them and will most likely forget because they already attached them once.  Not an optimal user experience.  I've seen where I can leverage Javascript, but then doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of the Django forms?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: So, what's your question? What kind of solution are you looking for? For security reasons, browsers don't allow file inputs to persist files, so that's out of question. Using JavaScript will give you the best solution user-experience wise. If you don't want to use JS, maybe split the form in two steps: first step for text based inputs and second for file inputs (but it will be a little more complex to setup).

Comment: @xyres  Thanks for the response.  Will consider.

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite validation logic in JS, you can submit the form using AJAX and let Django do the validation. This is probably the easiest and best solution.

Comment: Files are heavy resources, django does validation on server side so if validation fails it will be overhead to it. one thing you can do is write some validation logic using js at your front end and then if it passes you can pass your data and files to django. I know its kind of tedious but thats the tradeoff result you can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do u mean by form validation fail, files are disappeared and user has to re attach the files??....

If form validation fails you can raise an error in an webpage  through messages  that particular filefeild is not not valid .

The main reason forms do not get valid is because of how u set you model field attributes and views.... Yes indeed js, jQuery, ajax has leverage, but if you know how to work arround it is very easy to use.

It would be good if you have shown some code or an error what your facing. So the community members can help you without any confusion.

Cause there are many erros associated with form validation. So when u post an error it would be easy to resolve than giving n opinion in a bold fold.

Thankyou.

Comment: I was intending to ask a general question as I do not have a code specific question.  I was asking about the best approach.  What I mean by the files disappear is that apparently this is the normal behavior of browsers, to reject any files that have been uploaded in the browser if the form validation fails.  I am currently researching the JQuery, Ajax approach to submit a Django form that has both attachments and other form fields.

Comment: Ok , as you were saying files disappear in browser . The thing is browser has nothing to do with files storage. It's a server side thing. By using ajax, jQuery, js u can store the files for temporary as in sessions. Whereas django is more straight forward in this area. Hope it might help you:)

Comment: yes that's what I've found out.  I have continued to pursue this today.  I have opened up a new issue with the code that I have been able to scratch out thus far.